# Add a title to ACF form from frontend

Tags: page-template, advanced-custom-fields, front-end

I'm using ACF to make custom posts from the frontend.  I created a page in my theme, with the code:

```
// generate post title on submit
function auto_title_insert( $value ) {
  $value = $_POST["fields"]['field_5481df76aed49'].'-'.$_POST["fields"]['field_5481df80aed4a'].'-'.$_POST["fields"]['field_5481df86aed4b'].'-'.$_POST["fields"]['field_5481e101af995'];
  return $value;
}
add_filter( 'title_save_pre', 'auto_title_insert' );

// update post title on update
function my_acf_update_value( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    global $_POST;
    $new_title = $value;
    $new_slug = sanitize_title( $new_title );
    $my_post = array(
        'ID'         => $post_id,
        'post_title' => $new_title,
        'post_name'  => $new_slug,
        'post_type' => 'mycpt',
  );
  wp_update_post( $my_post );   
}
add_filter('acf/update_value', 'my_acf_update_value', 10, 3);

// other
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'custom_acf_deregister_styles', 100 );
function custom_acf_deregister_styles()
{
    if (! is_admin() )
    {
        wp_deregister_style( 'wp-admin' );
    }
}
acf_form_head();
get_header();
?>

    <div id="sidebar_layout" class="clearfix">
        <div class="sidebar_layout-inner">
            <div class="row grid-protection">

                <?php get_sidebar( 'left' ); ?>

                <!-- CONTENT (start) -->

                <div id="content" class="<?php echo themeblvd_get_column_class('content'); ?> clearfix" role="main">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <?php themeblvd_content_top(); ?>

                        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php get_template_part( 'content', themeblvd_get_part( 'page' ) ); ?>
                            <?php
                                $args = array(
                                    'post_id' => 'new',
                                    'field_groups' => array( 'acf_timesheet' ),
                                    'post_type' => 'tspg_timesheet',
                                    'post_title'  => $_POST["fields"]['field_5481df76aed49'].'-'.$_POST["fields"]['field_5481df80aed4a'].'-'.$_POST["fields"]['field_5481df86aed4b'].'-'.$_POST["fields"]['field_5481e101af995'],
                                );
                                acf_form( $args );
                            ?>



                            <?php themeblvd_page_footer(); ?>

                            <?php if ( themeblvd_supports( 'comments', 'pages' ) ) : ?>
                                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php themeblvd_content_bottom(); ?>
                    </div><!-- .inner (end) -->
                </div><!-- #content (end) -->

                <!-- CONTENT (end) -->

                <?php get_sidebar( 'right' ); ?>

            </div><!-- .grid-protection (end) -->
        </div><!-- .sidebar_layout-inner (end) -->
    </div><!-- .#sidebar_layout (end) -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

For some reason the post title is not generating and the post is not getting created.  What am I doing wrong?

I used the advice from this post: [How to update a custom post title from a front-end form using ACF fields?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169032/how-to-update-a-custom-post-title-from-a-front-end-form-using-acf-fields)

Comment: you can't have your filter functions inside the page template, by the time the template loads, those filters have already happened. put them in `functions.php`.

Comment: @Milo you're right, done.  Still does not fix the post creation issue though.  Any thoughts on why the custom post is not being created?

Comment: `wp_update_post` does not create a post; use `wp_insert_post` instead. Also, do you have a post type called "mycpt"??? I think you forget to change that with the correct post type. Other than those things, we can not check further because you are using a filter that is not from WordPress (`add_filter('acf/update_value'...`) and the support for it is off-topic here.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to add ACF form with content,  by one click check out [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-frontend-display/screenshots/)

Comment: Please do not post links as answers. Post a solution and explain how to solve the issue